# not able to migrate knowledge articles

Tags: knowledge, migration-tool, lightning-knowledge, informatica

I am trying to migrate `Knowledge Article` from source salesforce to destination salesforce environment. Source salesforce environment is `classic` while the destination is `lightning`.

In order to start with the simple insertion, I am trying to map source `KB_Article__kav` to destination `Knowledge__kav`.

I have mapped the following fields from source to destination.

```
isDeleted => isDeleted
PublishStatus =>PublishStatus
VersionNumber=>VersionNumber
IsLatestVersion=>IsLatestVersion

IsVisibleInApp=>IsVisibleInApp
IsVisibleInPkb=>IsVisibleInPkb
IsVisibleInCsp=>IsVisibleInCsp

IsVisibleInPrm=>IsVisibleInPrm
Language=>Language
Title=>Title
UrlName=>UrlName

CurrencyIsoCode=>CurrencyIsoCode
ArchivedDate=>ArchivedDate
Summary=>Summary
ArticleNumber=>ArticleNumber

FirstPublishedDate=>FirstPublishedDate

LastPublishedDate=>LastPublishedDate
ArticleArchivedDate =>ArticleArchivedDate
ArticleCaseAttachCount=>ArticleCaseAttachCount
ArticleTotalViewCount=>ArticleTotalViewCount
AssignmentNote=>AssignmentNote
**KnowledgeArticleId=>Id of destination KnowledgeArticleId**
```

To test the migration i am just passing single ID from source and then map it to the destination but I am getting following error

> WRT_8164 Error loading into target [Knowledge__kav] : Error received
> from salesforce.com. Fields []. Status code
> [CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY]. Message [entity type cannot be
> inserted: Knowledge]

I guess I have the required permission set enabled as well

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After enabling the `Knowledge User` permission in user profile , I am able to make an entry in `Knowledge__kav` using informatica